# Global clipboard unable to copy new content if webkit based browser is running

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, cinnamon, webkit

**Arch, cinnamon** all up to date. The issue even survived a fresh install. I have no idea how to further troubleshoot this thing.

I have tried using ***xfce*** and ***gnome*** to see if it was a cinnamon issue. Still persists though. **Chrome, Chromium or Opera**, all bring up the same issue.

No copy paste in any application.

Well, that is not completely true. **I can paste**. But it will paste the last thing I copied before launching a web-kit based browser.

Any ideas as to how I could further investigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: There isn't really a global clipboard in X. As the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection) describes, two applications have to communicate for copy and paste. X atoms stored on the root window describe the "owner" of the primary or secondary selection, and the application that wants to copy or paste has to find out the owner, and communicate with it to execute the actual paste.

If after launching a webkit based browser you always paste the last thing you selected, that means webkit somehow screws up the storage of ownership and prevents applications from setting it.

You can use `xtrace` to trace all X events, and I'd use that to compare a "healthy" cut&paste with what happens after webkit lauchnes. I haven't done this myself yet, though, so I can't provide step-by-step instructions.

It might als be interesting to run `xclipboard`, which is supposed to take over ownership of selections (again see Wikipedia article), and see what happens.