# Clipboard does not work

Tags: arch-linux, clipboard

I use Arch Linux (4.10.13-1-ARCH). Xfce environment.
Several days ago I assumed that clipboard stops working from/to Google Chrome, Onlyoffice, Okular, Gimp. It still working in a way like: Termianl <-> Mousepad, Terminal <-> Terminal, Mousepad <-> Mousepad,
and, what is more strange: Google Chrome <-> Google Chrome, Onlyoffice <-> Onlyoffice, etc. I tried different ways of copy-pasting: Ctrl+C/V, Ctrl/Shift+Insert, right click + copy/paste but nothing works.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223261/global-clipboard-unable-to-copy-new-content-if-webkit-based-browser-is-running). Seems related to starting a webkit-based browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox running on Antergos copy paste not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364219/firefox-running-on-antergos-copy-paste-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *was* a bug in gtk3 but is fixed already. If you update your system, and restart, the clipboard works again.